# Convert string as 'mm/dd/yyyy' to 'day of week, month name, year' in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am getting Facebook users' friends birthday back from Facebook in the following format:

```
10/07/1967 or just the day and month as 10/07
```

I want to display it as "October, 07, 1967" or "October, 07"

Is there a way to convert this string into a date and format it in Javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var MONTHS = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];
var myDate, myFormatDate;
var date_str ='10/07/1967';
var t = date_str.split("/");
if(t[2]) {
    myDate = new Date(t[2], t[0] - 1, t[1]);
    myFormatDate = MONTHS[myDate.getMonth()] + "," + myDate.getDate() + "," + myDate.getFullYear();
} else {
    myDate = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), t[0] - 1, t[1]);
    myFormatDate = MONTHS[myDate.getMonth()] + "," + mydate.getDate();
}
```

= RESULT:
= myDate -- the Date Object
= myFormatDate -- formated date string "October, 07, 1967"

Comment: This was easy to user and clear. I know the other plugins look great but this did the trick without adding another library. Thanks ijse

Answer (score 2):

To do it fast, without bells and whistles, you can first split your date

```
myDateParts = myDate.split("/");
```

Then build the new date from the parts:

```
myNewDate = new Date(myDateParts[2], myDateParts[1], myDateParts[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the awesome [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/) library. You'll be able to do what you want, and more ...

[No, i'm not involved in any way with DateJs, just a very satisfied user :-)]

Comment: DateJS is highly recommended!

Answer (score 0):

Using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/) you can convert a date with:

```
moment('10/07/1967', "MM/DD/YYYY").format("MMMM, DD, YY")
```

where the first part get a date from a string given a format (`"MM/DD/YYYY"`), then you just format the date as you wish giving another format (`"MMMM, DD, YY"`)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a framework, you could just pass in the string to the date constructor:

```
var birthday = new Date('10/07/1967');
```

The constructor will also accept strings without year, like '10/07'.
Then you can access each of the properties as you wish:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: There is something wrong with `birthday = new Date('10/07');`, it return `"Tue Oct 09 2001"`.

Comment: It's true that the year somehow defaults to 2001, but the date should be right? (new Date('10/07')).getDate() should return 7..?

Comment: Strange...me too and it works fine here. What is your code exactly?

Comment: birthday = new Date('10/07');
Date
birthday.toDateString()
"Sun Oct 07 2001"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5914/discussion-between-ijse-and-jorgen)

Comment: I can't connect to the chat, it seems, but now it seems correct..? "Sun Oct 07 2001"

Comment: This may be a bug. new Date("10/07/50").toDateString() == "Sat Oct 07 1950", new Date("10/07/49").toDateString() == "Sat Oct 07 2049", new Date("10/07/50").toDateString() == "Sat Oct 07 1950"

Comment: so, we should only use `new Date(year, month, day, hour, miniute, second) ` to ensure it work well.